Vuetify v-time-picker: Issue selecting zero (00) hour/minute: Invalid event arguments: event validation failed for event
Vuetify v-time-picker: Issue selecting time zero (00) hour/Minute
ERROR:
[Vue warn]: Invalid event arguments: event validation failed for event "input".
[Vue warn]: Invalid event arguments: event validation failed for event "change".
[Vue warn]: Invalid event arguments: event validation failed for event "update:minute".
ISSUE:
I need to update my store with the time selected in the v-time-picker component. However, when I select minutes or hours that include the digit zero (00), I encounter an error. As a result, the store is not updating correctly with the new time value.
For example, if I select 07:00, the store does not update. There is a strange behaviour in the component when clicking on the 00 digits. When I continue selecting or scrolling to the digit 00 (zero), at a certain point it finally registers the 00 digit and updates the store.
NOTE:
The error also appears in the official Vuetify documentation playground: Vuetify Time Pickers
CODE:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

import { useTimeStore } from '@/stores/register'

const { t } = useI18n()
const timeStore = useTimeStore()
const time = ref('')

const getCurrentTime = () => {
  const now = new Date()
  const hours = String(now.getHours()).padStart(2, '0')
  const minutes = String(now.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0')
  return `${hours}:${minutes}`
}

const updateTime = (newTime: string) => {
  console.log('1) updateTime:', newTime)
  timeStore.setSelectedTime(newTime)
}


onMounted(() => {
  const currentTime = getCurrentTime()
  time.value = currentTime
  timeStore.setSelectedTime(currentTime)
})
</script>
<template>
  <v-responsive>
    <v-row justify="space-around">
      <v-time-picker
        class="time-picker--container"
        v-model="time"
        format="24hr"
        @update:modelValue="updateTime"
        scrollable
        :title="t('timePicker.title')"
      ></v-time-picker>
    </v-row>
  </v-responsive>
</template>

How can I resolve this issue to ensure the store updates correctly when select zero minutes/hour?

It's not an error, it's a warning, and shouldn't prevent the update of v-model or the calling of your updateTime function.  If it does, we'll need more debugging information.  When you log newTime, is it correct? If so, the error is somewhere with the store, not the component. If you want to get rid of the warning you'll likely need to report it to the Vuetify team on their github as it's an issue internal to their component.

The newTime is logged correctly in the component and store except for the 00 time/minutes value, which triggers a warning most of the time. If I continue scrolling or changing 00 value somehow, the warning disappears, then newTime was logged updating store correctly. The solution I found was to use native html  <input class="time-input" type="time" v-model="time" @input="updateTime" :title="t('timePicker.title')"/>.
The input has the same layout as vuetify timer-picker in chrome
android mobile and now the component work as expected.

I have a same problem, also when I edit current time 12:00 and I change to 13:00 it doens't change, even in the documentation examples

@SimonKlimek I decide to use native html <input class="time-input" type="time" v-model="time" @input="updateTime" :title="t('timePicker.title')"/>. The native input has the same layout as vuetify timer-picker for chrome android mobile and after that my component behaviour as expected
